# JavascriptMVC and RubyOnRail integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, javascriptmvc

I saw one question related to folder structure on JMVC and ROR. My question is different.
I am new to both and I want to know how to integrate JMVC created files with RubyOnRail created files.
Think like this: RoR creates view pages and JMVC also create view pages. then which one will I use?

This question will help me understand **how to use JMVC with any other server side MVC based framework.**

If possible, please give me code example. Thank you.

I have installed JMVC and saw it creating folders for controller, model and view with files. Therefore my confusion!